# String and Integer replace for php dynamic values

Tags: php

I want to replace a string and integer values in php as per the requirement , the word is AIRTEL RC SUCCESS AND CONFIRM. NUM: 9999999999 AMT: 10 TXID: 7894561237. YOUR COMPANY BAL IS: 299.10 . I want to remove YOUR COMPANY BAL IS 299.10

Comment: <?php //$u = str_replace(" YOUR COMPANY BAL IS"," ",$dis);  ?> thIS Format but i want to remove integer also

Comment: You can find the position of "YOUR COMPANY" and then do a substring to get the text up to that part.

Answer (score 1):

`$u = preg_replace("/ YOUR COMPANY BAL IS: \d+\.?\d+/", " ", $dis);`

Comment: i cant get the result on this

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<?php
$str = "AIRTEL RC SUCCESS AND CONFIRM. NUM: 9999999999 AMT: 10 TXID: 7894561237. YOUR COMPANY BAL IS: 299.10.";
echo preg_replace("/YOUR COMPANY BAL IS: \d+\.?\d+./", "", $str);
```

Output:

AIRTEL RC SUCCESS AND CONFIRM. NUM: 9999999999 AMT: 10 TXID: 7894561237.

Comment: I cant get the result

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is it not working as per your question?